# c# remove elements from 2nd list

Tags: c#, list, removeall

I want to remove all elements from list2 that belong to list1. 
I noticed that my code is very slow if it has e.g. 50k elements in both lists. I am iterating over all elements in list1, and if element is contained in list2, i remove such element from list2. 
What would be efficient approach?

```
        public static int RemoveDuplicatesFromSecondRange(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
        {
           int removed = 0;

           foreach (string el in list1)
           {
              list2.Remove(el);
              removed++;
           }

           return removed;
        }
```

Comment: use for loop instead, and use `if(list1.Contains(list2[x]))` this might give you a little boost. A better solution is to go for LinkedList for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int RemoveDuplicatesFromSecondRange(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  var beforeCount = list2.Count;

  var inList2Only = list2.Except(list1).ToList();

  list2.Clear();
  list2.AddRange(inList2Only);

  return beforeCount - inList2Only.Count;
}
```

Comment: list2.Clear() is also clearing inList2Only so i would make it: list2 = list.Except(list1).ToList();

Comment: @NenadBirešev: Updated, thank you.

Comment: Now is better but it should be return list2.Count - list1.Count;

Comment: @NenadBirešev: The number of items removed from `list2` is the difference between the original size and the resulting size. `list1` contains all items, and `list2` is a subset. This is why I think `list1.Count - list2.Count` is correct.

Comment: Hi it is not correct. The function is removing all elements that are in list1 from list2. Meaning list1 is not full size. You need to declare a variable int total = list.Count at the first line, and then return total - list2.Count.

Comment: @NenadBirešev: Point taken about `list2` being the subset. I edited it to use the difference between all items (`list2`) and the remaining ones (`inList2Only`), which should give the # removed.

Comment: It is going to return 0 always as list2 is the same as inList2Only

Comment: @NenadBirešev: Augh you're right, this is why I don't like editing lists in place :-) I added the variable to track the count before adjusting `list2`.

Comment: All correct. I would in addition edit list2 = list2.Except(list1).ToList(); because there is no need to create new variable, clear elements in list2, then add all elements to list2

Comment: @NenadBirešev: The changes must be visible in `list2` after the method exits.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave you to performance test this...

```
public static int RemoveDuplicatesFromSecondRange2(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  var exCount = list2.Select(s => s).Except(list1).Count();
  return list2.Count - exCount;
}
```

What this does is create a 3rd list which has only elements that occur in `list2` and not in `list1`.

Internally I believe LINQ uses an optimisation, creating a HashSet giving effectively something like this...

```
public static int RemoveDuplicatesFromSecondRange3(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  var h = new HashSet<string>(list1);
  var exCount = list2.Select(s => s).Except(h).Count();
  return list2.Count - exCount;
}
```

(instead of scanning the whole of list1 on every test of each element of list2, it first creates an indexed data structure allowing much faster lookup in list).

Your code seems to want only the count, but your question says you want a list with entries removed...

```
public static List<string> RemoveDuplicatesFromSecondRange4(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  return list2.Select(s => s).Except(list1).ToList();
  /* OR
  var h = new HashSet<string>(list1);
  return list2.Select(s => s).Except(h).ToList();
  */
}
```